# Process Monitor Results from two Citrix Servers Application Error

Tags: microsoft-word, api, procmon

I have two Citrix Servers both running an in-house bespoke software. The software generates files using a word 2003 mail merge template which runs VBA code to query an oracle database. Anyway the software works fine so taking that out the equation the mail merge function direct in Word 2003 fails on one Server but works on the other.

I have build both Servers and re-build this Server from the ground up and still it fails with a generic error.

Using Process Monitor and spending hours cross referencing the results the only real difference is that the broken Server has these added parts for each attempt at file access:

> "WINWORD.EXE","QueryStandardInformationFile","C:\Users\xxxx\WINDOWS","SUCCESS","AllocationSize:
> 0, EndOfFile: 0, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory:
> True"
>
> "WINWORD.EXE","QueryBasicInformationFile","C:\Users\xxxx\WINDOWS","SUCCESS","CreationTime:
> 06/08/2014 08:07:31, LastAccessTime: 06/08/2014 08:07:33,
> LastWriteTime: 06/08/2014 08:07:33, ChangeTime: 06/08/2014 08:07:33,
> FileAttributes: D"

Whereas the working Server does not try the QueryStandardInformationFile and simply has:

> "WINWORD.EXE","QueryBasicInformationFile","C:\Users\xxxx\WINDOWS","SUCCESS","CreationTime:
> 24/07/2014 08:51:33, LastAccessTime: 24/07/2014 08:51:50,
> LastWriteTime: 24/07/2014 08:51:50, ChangeTime: 24/07/2014 08:51:50,
> FileAttributes: D"

I have tried literally everything from making users local admins to exporting and importing security policies, etc. I cannot figure out what the problem is and this being the last part of the troubleshooting puzzle; I simply have no explanation as to why they are behaving differently.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: One thing I find odd is the file path you quoted of C:\Users\xxxx\WINDOWS (normally it's something like C:\Users\xxxx\documents or C:\Users\xxxx\desktop). I've never seen that before or was that merely a typo.

Comment: Yeah its c:\users\%username%\Windows as well as c:\users\%username%\Desktop, etc. Lots of these entries.

Comment: Grr hadn't finished! I have now fixed the problem as below :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to one Server using roaming profiles and one Server having roaming profiles (folder redirection) failing causing local user folders to be used. Even though this was not apparent from the process monitor logs.

After fixing Roaming profiles now both Servers are working as expected. Must be something to do with local user profile write permissions or something along those lines!